# The best way to get all children taxons of a root taxon

Tags: doctrine-orm, sylius, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu based on the taxons from the root taxon 'Category'. This is the menu I want to get :

- Taxon A

  - Taxon A1
  - Taxon A2
- Taxon B

  - Taxon B1

    - Taxon B1a
    - Taxon B1b

I coded something which worked this way:

First, I overrode the taxon repository

```
use Sylius\Bundle\...\TaxonRepository as BaseRepository;

class TaxonRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function findForMenu()
    {
        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->innerJoin('t.taxonomy', 'ta')
            ->innerJoin('ta.root', 'r')
            ->where('ta.name = :name')
            ->andWhere('t.parent = r')
            ->setParameter('name', 'Category')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Then, I created a menu builder

```
class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;
    private $repository;

    public function __construct($factory, TaxonRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function createMain(Request $request)
    {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

        foreach ($this->repository->findForMenu() as $taxon) {
            $menu->addChild($this->buildChild($taxon));
        }

        return $menu;
    }

    private function buildChild(Taxon $taxon)
    {
        $item = $this->factory->createItem($taxon->getName());

        foreach ($taxon->getChildren() as $child) {
            $item->addChild($this->buildChild($child));
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

It worked well but because of the lazy loading there were a lot of queries so, I decided to use the behaviour of the ClosureTreeRepository (of Gedmo). I realized that I can't do that as you have to inherit from the repository of Sylius and you cannot inherit from the ClosureTreeRepository of Gedmo.

Any hints on how to get the taxon tree well constructed via the ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You get lots of queries because of lazy loading. To prevent that you should update your query by adding `->select()` and select all you need to build a menu.

Something like this:

```
class TaxonRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    public function findForMenu()
    {
        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t', 'ta', 'r')
            ->innerJoin('t.taxonomy', 'ta')
            ->innerJoin('ta.root', 'r')
            ->where('ta.name = :name')
            ->andWhere('t.parent = r')
            ->setParameter('name', 'Category')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```